# How I can find all extension methods in solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, extension-methods

How I can find all extension methods in solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I were doing it I would search all files for the string "( this " -- your search string may differ based on your formatting options.

**EDIT**: After a little bit of experimentation, the following seems to work for me with high precision using "Find in Files" (Ctrl-Shift-F)

- Search string: "`\( this [A-Za-z]`"  (minus quotes, of course)
- Match case: unchecked
- Match whole word: unchecked
- Use: Regular Expressions
- Look at these file types: "*.cs"

Comment: "this" is often passed in as an argument - I guess you'd need to match the "(this type name" pattern, followed by "," or ")", and with any amount of whitespace in the middle. Not a simple regex (I didn't even try...)

Comment: Yes, but in my formatting it would be "( this, ", not "( this " so it wouldn't match.

Comment: ...except when it's the only argument, so perhaps a regex with "( this [A-Za-z]", though I just ran it on one of my solutions and only found 3 examples of it passed as an argument and 50 or so extension methods (lots of HtmlHelper extensions for MVC).

Comment: is it always a space infront of 'this'?

Comment: It depends on your formatting settings.  It always is for me.

Comment: As Search String you must use `\(\s*this\s*IEnumerator` (in case search extension for "IEnumerator"), because between {"(" and "this"} and {"this" and "<Type>"} can exist any number of whiteSpaces

Answer (score 7):

I'd look at the generated assemblies using reflection; iterate through the static types looking for methods with `[ExtensionAttribute]`...

```
static void ShowExtensionMethods(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.IsClass && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
            && type.BaseType == typeof(object)
            && type.GetConstructors().Length == 0)
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods(
                BindingFlags.Static |
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {
                ParameterInfo[] args;

                if ((args = method.GetParameters()).Length > 0 &&
                    HasAttribute(method,
                      "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName + "." + method.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tthis " + args[0].ParameterType.Name
                        + " " + args[0].Name);
                    for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + args[i].ParameterType.Name
                            + " " + args[i].Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
static bool HasAttribute(MethodInfo method, string fullName)
{
    foreach(Attribute attrib in method.GetCustomAttributes(false))
    {
        if (attrib.GetType().FullName == fullName) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, it can be any attribute called ExtensionAttribute, it ned not be the same type as supplied in System.Code.dll.  This allows you to use this feature while targeting .NET 2.

Comment: True; indeed, I've used several - in LINQBridge, and MiscUtil among others... I'll update it...

Comment: It does not need that namespace either  :)  Any attribute named ExtensionAttribute will work.

Comment: OK, that last is news to me - but getting a bit into the exotic now ;-p I'll leave it "as is", but good info, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the code in this article about [how to find extension methods targeting object](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/1/10/how-to-find-extension-methods-targeting-object.html) could be used? Could for example be rewritten slightly and use it to dump all extension methods instead of just those targeting `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to check the sourcecode (just look for `(this ...` in the files) or your running programm by reflection (in this case, this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721800/using-reflection-to-check-if-a-method-is-extension-method) discussion can help you)?

Comment: Yep. Not to forget about whitespace and newlines between the bracket and `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution wide text search with a regex matching your coding style. Something like `"( *this +"` (added the first optional space to get some error tollerance).