# How to navigate to extension methods such as MapHttpRoute of HttpRouteCollectionExtension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, class-extensions

In Visual Studio 2012 I'd like to navigate to the MapHttpRoute method from the HttpRouteCollection class.

So for example if I go to the definition of Routes of Routes.MapHttpRoute(),  I see Routes is an instance of HttpRouteCollection class. However if I check the definition of HttpRouteCollection I can't find the MapHttpRoute method. Are extension methods hidden?

Comment: They're not "hidden", they're just defined in another type.

Comment: You should note that they are actually exposed via the `HttpRouteCollectionExtensions` static class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they aren't hidden. They are extension methods that reside in the `HttpRouteCollectionExtensions` static class, and since you're using an instance of `HttpRouteCollection`, you're seeing them as an available API.

[image]

Another way you can tell, should this scenario come up in the future, is to look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835153(v=vs.118).aspx) for the method in question.

Comment: I can get to this if I right click on MapHttpRoute() to see it's definition. My question is from the HttpRouteCollection class, how would I know these extension methods exist for that class?

Comment: You wouldn't, simply from looking at the `HttpRouteCollection` class, since it is not static. If the `HttpRouteCollection` class was static, I'm sure these methods would reside in that class. There are existings [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857489/how-i-can-find-all-extension-methods-in-solution) on how to find all extension methods, which may help answer your question

Comment: So how does HttpRouteCollectionExtensions extend to HttpRouteCollection? From your picture I only see that HttpRouteCollectionExtensions implements IHttpRoute.

Comment: Look at the first parameter in the methods, an instance of `HttpRouteCollection`, using the `this` keyword makes them "extension methods." You couldn't write `var s = "hello"; s.MapHttpRoute()` because `s` is a string, not an instance of `HttpRouteCollection`. If you are looking for some white paper, you should google extension methods in C#.

Comment: your explanation of this keyword was very helpful, thanks for this!

Comment: @MilesMorales no problem - glad I could help.