# How to determine one method "Is extension method of a Type or not?"

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to write a method named IsExtensionMethod that its signature is :

```
public bool IsExtensionMethod(object anObject, string method)
{
    // if method was an extension for anObject return true else false
}
```

How can i do it?

I tried for following code but in some cases it's return value is incorrect:

```
public bool IsExtensionMethod(object anObject, string method)
{
    return anObject.GetType().GetMethods().Where(item => item.Name == method).Count() == 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using reflection to check if a method is "Extension Method"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721800/using-reflection-to-check-if-a-method-is-extension-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler adds a `CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute` attribute to extension methods when it compiles them.  Look for this attribute.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx

Comment: You are right. But I want to have aforementioned method. your vice is to search method in any loaded assemblies. Is any simple way?

Comment: @Saeed Afshari, yes, you need to search for the extension methods, just like the compiler does.  If this is something you need to do often you can do the search and then cache the results.  You can even do it as a post-compile process and create a file that goes along with the dll like `mylibrary.dll.extensions.xml` or something equivalent.