# Is there a way to determine whether a parameter has this modifier?

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods

I would like to determine if a parameter has `this` modifier using `Reflection`.I have looked at properties of `ParameterInfo` class, but couldn't find anything useful.I know the *extension methods* are just syntactic sugars but I believe there should be a way to determine whether a method is an extension method.

The only thing that distinguishes extension methods from other static methods (that are defined in a *static*, *public* class) is `this` modifier.

For example this is not an extension method:

```
public static int Square(int x) { return x * x; }
```

But this is:

```
public static int Square(this int x) { return x * x; }
```

So how can I distinguish between two methods using `Reflection` or something else if possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using reflection to check if a method is “Extension Method”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721800/using-reflection-to-check-if-a-method-is-extension-method)?

Comment: In each language that supports them, there are two sides to extension methods: invoking (reflection at compile-time) and declaring (source code). See the relevant spec. [[C# 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) section 7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations, section 10.6.9 Extension methods.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not *exactly* the same, but you can check whether the method has the [`ExtensionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx) applied to it.

```
var method = type.GetMethod("Square");
if (method.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false))
{
    // Yup, it's an extension method
}
```

Now I say it's not exactly the same, because you *could* have written:

```
[Extension]
public static int Square(int x) { return x * x; }
```

... and the compiler would still pick it up as an extension method. So this *does* detect whether it's an extension method (assuming it's in a static top-level non-generic type) but it *doesn't* detect for certain whether the source code had the `this` modifier on the first parameter.