# Using extension methods defined in C# from F# code

Tags: c#, f#, extension-methods

I have a series of extension methods defined for various classes
in a C# library. I'm currently writing some F# code and instead of rewriting
that code I would simply like to use my existing extension methods in my F# code.

I have added a reference to the library and used the
open statement to import the namespace,
but the extension methods to not appear in F#

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Update:

In the current version of F#, you can simply consume extension methods by adding

```
open TheNamespaceOfExtensionMethod
```

to your source file (just like you do in C# with a `using` directive) and simply call the extension method as if it was a normal instance method.

By the way, you can always call them directly just like a normal static method and pass the object reference as the first parameter without any directives if you want. An extension method is simply a static method decorated with `ExtensionAttribute` under the hood.

#### Original answer (before F# 2010 beta; not true anymore, as Dykam points out):

I don't think extension methods are supported by F#. You can always call them directly just like a normal static method and pass the object reference as the first parameter.

Comment: +1. Exactly, extension methods are a language feature, not a CLR feature. They are really syntactic sugar to make certain kinds of static method look like instance methods.

Answer (score 9):

Being able to 'import' C#/VB extension methods will be supported in the next release of F#.

See also

[F# extension methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702256/f-extensions-in-c)

for more detail on the topic.