# FLinq SQL "IN Clause"

Tags: f#

I am trying haplessly to create an "IN CLause" through f# linq - but can't seem to get it.  I have tried two options:

Iterating over the list of days as part of the sequence expression:

```
let getHistoricalQuotes (securityId:int) (days:string seq) =
    let results = 
        Query.query <@ seq { 
            for day in days do
                for sq in db.SecurityQuote do
                    if sq.SecurityId =?! securityId && sq.Day = day then
                        yield sq ;
        } @>
```

And  a List.exists clause:

```
let getHistoricalQuotes (securityId:int) (days:string list) =
    let results = 
        Query.query <@ seq { 
            for sq in db.SecurityQuote do
                if sq.SecurityId =?! securityId && List.exists (fun d -> d = sq.Day) days then
                    yield sq ;
        } @> 

    results
```

Both are giving me:

> base {System.SystemException} =
>   {"Method
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.String,System.Boolean]
>   ToFSharpFunc[String,Boolean](System.Converter`2[System.String,System.Boolean])'
>   has no supported translation to SQL."}

as always, thanks for the help in advance...

---

rewrote to:

```
let getHistoricalQuotes (securityId:int) (days:string list) =
    let results = 
        Query.query <@ 
            Query.join
                db.SecurityQuote 
                days
                (fun sq -> if(sq.SecurityId =?! securityId) then sq.Day else "") 
                (fun d -> d) 
                (fun sq d -> sq)  @> 

    results
```

and got this excepion:

> System.Exception was unhandled
>   Message=The following construct was
>   used in query but is not recognised by
>   the F#-to-LINQ query translator: Value
>   (["2010/01/04"; "2010/02/01";
>   "2010/03/01"; "2010/04/01";
>   "2010/05/03";  "2010/06/01";
>   "2010/07/01"; "2010/08/02";
>   "2010/09/01"; "2010/10/01"; 
>   "2010/11/01"; "2010/12/01";
>   "2010/01/29"; "2010/02/26";
>   "2010/03/31";  "2010/04/30";
>   "2010/05/31"; "2010/06/30";
>   "2010/07/30"; "2010/08/31"; 
>   "2010/09/30"; "2010/10/29";
>   "2010/11/30"; "2010/12/31"]) This is
>   not a valid query expression. Check
>   the specification of permitted queries
>   and consider moving some of the query
>   out of the quotation

and removing the quotations didn't cause an error - but it generated a incredibly incorrect query (selext * from historicalquote)

---

Cheating for now, until I can come back and fix the problem - but at least I can keep the signature the same, though I will be thrashing the database.

```
let getHistoricalQuotes (securityId:int) (days:string list) =
    let getQuote (day) =  
        Query.query <@ seq { 
            for sq in db.SecurityQuote do
                if sq.SecurityId =?! securityId && sq.Day = day then
                    yield sq ;
        } @> |> Seq.head

    List.map (fun day -> getQuote day) days
```

---

Per Will below i tried this

```
let getHistoricalQuotes (securityId:int) (days:string list) =
    let results =  
        Query.query <@ seq { 
            for sq in db.SecurityQuote do
                if sq.SecurityId =?! securityId && days.Contains(sq.Day) then
                    yield sq ;
        } @> 
    results
```

But it doesn't compile

> Error 1   The field, constructor or
>   member 'Contains' is not defined

---

Finally - (Thank you will):

```
let getHistoricalQuotes (securityId:int) (days:string array) =
    let results =  
        Query.query <@ seq { 
            for sq in db.SecurityQuote do
                if sq.SecurityId =?! securityId && days.Contains(sq.Day) then
                    yield sq ;
        } @> 
    results
```

And yes  - you need to open System.Linq - Are those extension methods, or at elast partially - they must be,

Comment: I just read somewhere that F# might not support consuming extension methods... I'm looking for an alternative...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777247/using-extension-methods-defined-in-c-from-f-code

Comment: Try System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(days, day) .. assuming F# supports consuming generic methods..

Comment: Glad to have helped, and good to see that F# does support extensions - they're nice syntactic sugar.  With `open System.Linq` in place, check out the other methods hanging off any IEnumerable object - there's alot to play with, and most work with EF.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already exists in Linq, but the opposite of what you're use to:

```
days.Contains(day)
```

Comment: It doesn't compile for me.   'Contains' is not defined.  I must be putting it in the wrong place.  I am editing above...

Comment: I'm a C# developer, and can barely read F#, but Contains is part of the .Net framework so should work across all languages.  I normally write code similar to this:  `var validValues = new[] {1,2,3}; var result = source.Where(item => validValues.Contains(item.Property1));`  Hopefully you can read C# and translate...

Comment: I take it you're importing/using System.Linq? (or whatever the equivalent statement is in F#)

Comment: Ah, "open System.Linq" ... you'll make an F# developer of me yet ;)