# F# type extensions in C# project: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension missed?

Tags: c#, f#, extension-methods

I'm diving into F# and it's very fascinating. I'm trying to marry Optional Types and C# like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702256/f-extensions-in-c/702321#702321). Pretty interesting thing... however I miss something important I guess:

```
#light
namespace MyFSharp

// C# way
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
module ExtensionMethods =
    [<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
    let Great(s : System.String) = "Great"


using System;
using MyFSharp;  // reference the F# dll
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = "foo";
        //s.Awesome(); // no
        Console.WriteLine(s.Great());  // yes
    }
}
```

That's very simple - and I guess it's too early for me or something... I get:

```
The type 'Extension' is not defined
```

Maybe it's too early... but I just don't get why it isn't found.

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: You should show the F# and C# code in two different pre blocks. I mean to say add a "C#:" in normal text above using System; to avoid confusion. On first look, it looks like you are trying to use a class/Main method in F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods need to be static in a static class. Does F# actually emit it as such? If not, then you are out of luck.

**Update**

I just tried it, and it appears to emit static class and method. I got the same error as you, but fixed by compiling as:

> fsc -r System.Core test.fs

Then looking at the output of the assembly in Reflector, it looks all good and should work.

Answer (score 7):

Does your F# project have a reference to the `System.Core` assembly?

EDIT: Hmm... perhaps explicitly call it `ExtensionAttribute` instead of just `Extension`? Maybe if the namespace is specified (instead of just a simple name) it doesn't try with the `Attribute` suffix?

Comment: Yes, it has. By default afaik VS adds this ref

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your F# project is targeting the .Net Framework 2.0.

Try changing it to .Net Framework 3.5 (under the project properties -> Application).